# How dangerous are the equivalent of flying piranhas to the ecosystem?

Tags: aliens, fauna

**A zoo containing species from two different planets houses some very voracious specimens. I am calling them Galorian Nibblers**. The best way to describe them would be as a mix of starlings and piranhas. They fly, they flock and they nip pieces of flesh from their prey until nothing but bones are left. What's worse, they signal each other as well.

Each Nibbler measures only 15 to 19 inches (38,1-48.26 cm) in length and has a wingspan of 1 to 2 feet (30-60 cm). A healthy specimen weighs up to three pounds (1.4 kg). Each female can carry one to two eggs. A flocks population can more than double in a single year, assuming optimal breeding conditions (e.g. food supply and temperature). Their specialized natural predators aren't present on earth.

Nibblers are obligate carnivores and can tolerate high temperatures, though they don't do well in the cold. They come from a mostly dry planet so they are adapted to preserve water. Flocks of Nibblers scour areas in search of food and follow the calls of their kin. When danger is spotted they either form a tight flock or scatter and hide. Unlike earth birds, they don't nest and instead carry their eggs with them, depositing them somewhere safe before going on the offensive (they can even take turns guarding them).

**If they were let loose on our poor blue planet what would be the damages? Could the ecosystem survive this invasive species? (I don't care about the humans)**

Comment: "Only" ? your nibblers are quite large !  a meter in wing span ! do you mean 3.2 pounds, or 14.5 kg ?

Comment: I'd suspect 3.2lb/1.45 kg.

Comment: We don't have sufficient information about their natural habitat to know how well they'd survive on earth, or how able they are to adapt to an alien environment.

Comment: Cough cough... sorry about that. My math is bad.

Comment: [Piranhas 2: the spawning](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Piranha_II:_The_Spawning) used genetically engineered hybrid of flying fish and piranhas.

Comment: If by "the ecosystem" you mean life on earth, If they're too competent as predators they'll eventually die off from starvation and the remaining animal species take over. Everything is fine. If they're more competent the the pre-existing predators, but not to the point of being able to hunt everything in their habitat to extinction the previous predators go extinct and life goes on for everyone else. Everything is fine. So long as the event doesn't wipe out all life on earth, life will just bounce back and the vacant niches will get filled by new species.

Comment: I think you need to make an addition to your question. Piranhas do not attack the animals entering their water unless the animal is bleeding. Do your nibblers smell blood and hunt the bleeding animal?

Comment: @rainbowcat No. They attack on sight.

Comment: Pirahanas are not THAT agressive. Check out [this dad who put pirahanas in his pond](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0SuNIoS1yxA) and didn't even get a little bit eaten.

Comment: Attacking any animal sight is not an effective hunting strategy. Most large prey animals have hides of various thickness and toughness, the first nibbler to attack any specific individual is going to get a mouthful of tough skin - whereas, if they were to hone in on an animal that is already being attacked, they have a chance of getting in at the more nutritious flesh beneath the skin. The effective thing to do is for the flock to coordinate and pick off one individual from a herd, which has the convenient effect of letting the rest of the herd survive to be preyed on tomorrow.

Comment: It's worth noting that on earth we have ... eagles. Which pretty much fit your description in terms of choice of food and means of aquiring it, and only differ in behaviour.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let’s first consider a simple natural ecosystem. Here the following aspects are relevant to limit the population of the top predator, say lions, and their prey:

- Lions can only prey on sufficiently large prey. Otherwise the energy required to hunt would be less than the energy gained. (Smaller predators can hunt smaller prey because they have less weight to move around.)
- Lions can only hunt on prey that they can easily spot and hunt. For example lions do not usually prey on mice because mice escape or hide using tunnels, canopy, etc. In fact, lions are specialised on a few prey animals.
- Lions reduce the population of the prey they can hunt until it is so rare that the energy required for finding prey becomes too much, which in turn limits the lion population.
- Lions do not hunt when they are full.

Now, let’s consider your nibblers: They appear to be specialised on a hunting large animals as a flock, which requires a lot of energy.
If this is the niche they fill in their natural habitat, they will consequentially not be very good at hunting smaller animals, for example because they lack maneuverability.
As a result, a nibbler flock should roughly be equivalent to a lion or pack¹ of lions, i.e., it rests most of the day and only attacks large prey animals when hungry. I would therefore postulate that you can have an stable Earth ecosystem where the top predators (lions, tigers, wolves, etc.) are replaced by nibblers.

The more interesting question is whether this stable state will actually be reached if you suddenly introduce nibblers into our ecosystem.
Here the biggest problem is that nibblers reproduce quickly and are initially presented a plethora of prey.
This may lead to a sudden overpopulation of nibblers, who eradicate their prey species and then become extinct before a stable equilibrium can be reached.
Or a stable equilibrium is reached after initial heavy population oscillations (of course, some prey species may survive the nibblers, while others do not).
A third option is that nibblers eradicate all larger animals and survive by being the new top predator that hunts smaller animals with meagre efficiency.

The crucial question here is whether the prey species can survive the first minimum before the initial surge of nibblers shrinks due to lack of food.
Here, there are several aspects that may tip the scale:

- Can some of the prey (i.e., large animals) escape the nibblers, e.g., by hiding or living in a different climate?
- To what extents will the nibblers spend their excess energy on reproduction and further hunting? For example, do the nibblers focus on reproduction or resting when they are full, or do they spend all the energy on hunting further and more thoroughly? Since nibblers are not adapted to our ecosystem, both can be plausible.
- How well can your nibblers metabolise earth animals? Since they are from a different planet, it is plausible that they can use only a small portion (or none) of the food they consume. If they shall be able to reproduce under these conditions at all, they need to eat an excessive amount of food. This in turn makes a scarcity of prey hit much harder and be a possible cause of nibbler extinction (before the prey goes extinct).
- Do nibblers cannibalise? This can be a way that the nibbler population controls itself (to an extent) once other prey borders on extinction.

A good way of looking at this may be to make the nibblers’ natural habitat plausible, ideally without a natural predator.

---

¹ or *pride* if you want to be posh.

Answer (score 3):

**Very dangerous, but adding a predator to an ecosystem will not destroy it**

At first glance, very dangerous animals indeed. But your question is, if there would be danger to the ecosystem ?

Sure, they breed fast in good circumstances (the 2 eggs hatch each year) they will become a plague and their prey animals could be forced to migrate to colder regions, or even die out. Now, there is less prey. As a result, your species will breed slower, more nibblers will die as a result of food shortage.

Your animal is an invasive predator species, it is well equipped. It could replace the top of the food chain, endanger your existing, larger predators.. but *ecosystems* are quite resilient ! A real disaster for an ecosystem would be elimination of the *lower* food chain. That hasn't happened in this case, your nibblers need relatively large prey, and they operate only on land.

Let them escape.. let's have some Hitchcock-style fun !

Answer (score 3):

**Not as dangerous as you think**

Your flock can have a big problem here. They seem to be build to predate. That means the flock must be able to hunt prey. If we look at our current ecosystem we don't see any flying flock predators. It is more economical to hunt individually. Your flock will stand out, giving a lot of creatures the ability to scatter and run. That is already an energy sink a single predator cannot use. Now imagine the cost and return of a whole flock! They cannot get enough energy from smaller prey. It isn't impossible to survive, but their numbers will likely drop to more economical sizes. Still there's larger prey. Let's look at them.

A tiger can easily kill a human. This begs the question, why isn't it normal prey? In most cases humans aren't on their regular menu.

This is because of the danger to the tiger. The tiger can receive damage. Any damages that interfere with hunting and last some time can be incredibly dangerous. Starvation and over exertion are right around the corner. It is a too high risk/reward.

Any larger prey will quickly present such dangers to a small flying piranha. If the flying piranha descent on the cow, deer, fox or whatever there is a lot of movement. The flying creatures are unfortunately relatively delicate creatures. Their wings can easily be damaged the moment the prwy takes off. Their wings might be ok the first time and the next, but statistics tell us the chances rise if the numbers are large enough.

The premise of flying schools of piranhas seems scary, but their numbers will dwindle quickly as they get damaged or succumb to starvation. The ecosystem will be fine and the flying piranhas will probably survive as they try out better tactics. Maybe then once in a while they still go out in a flying school of death.

Answer (score 2):

**Nibblers die in a week or two...at best.**

Wrong habitat, wrong environmental cues, and no familiar prey. A recipe for starvation.

But let's put that aside and consider the biological similarities between Nibblers and Blues at a molecular level.

If the Nibblers and Blues AREN'T biologically compatible at a molecular level, then the Nibblers will starve. It doesn't matter how many Blues they feed upon -- they cannot digest the nutrients that they need from the alien molecules. The Blues are essentially indigestible.

If the Nibblers and Blues ARE biologically compatible (Wow! That's an *amazing* coincidence!), then the Nibblers will be vulnerable to every micoroganism they encounter in the Blue environment. With no immunity, they will soon succumb to illness.

However, it's a two-way street: Nibbler microrganisms will run wild in the open, unprotected Blue environment, causing perhaps a mass extinction and civilization collapse.

Of course, that mass extinction will happen anyway simply from the Nibblers being present on the Blue planet, whether or not they escape. Life finds a way....

This obvious risk of catastrophic consequences from mixing compatible organisms suggests that the Blues test before bringing new species to their zoo...or they would already be dead. Therefore, the Nibblers are likely to be biologically incompatible with the Blues, else they would not be on the planet. So starvation (not plague) it is.

Comment: Blues?! What are we? A band? Seriously though that was clever. From now on I’m calling  all of humanity “the Blues”.

Answer (score 1):

Locust hordes would do a lot more damage.

Birds have to be lightweight in order to fly, which means all the big muscles are used for flight, bones are hollow and fragile, etc. The only dangerous birds are flightless, notably the feathered honeybadgers, also known as casoar: these can murder you with one swipe from their huge claws. Being adapted to walking instead of flying means they can afford the huge leg muscles.

Since your birds are not vegetarians, the trees are safe. They're too large to manoeuver in a forest, so every animal that lives in a forest or can hide in one is also safe from the flying piranhas. So, assuming they successfully adapt, they would most likely strongly reduce the population of large animals living in savannah, steppes, or fields. This lack of food would control the population of flying piranhas. Assuming no human intervention, you could therefore expect less savannah/steppe herbivores eating tree saplings, which means over the long run, forests would extend.

The ideal predator would most likely be a nocturnal snake.

Answer (score 0):

**They don't last long.**

If the flying piranhas first appear next to a body of water they might go into it and become regular pirhanas. Otherwise the flying piranhas will fly around for a few minutes before their gills dry out and they suffocate.

Comment: True, however these aren't flying piranhas. They're just _like_ flying piranhas, being basically scaly birds or small pterosaurs. They have lungs, not gills.

Answer (score 0):

In any Eco system, preys always outnumber predators otherwise all preys die and then all predators.

Also preys have techniques to escape the predators.

If your flying piranhas enter an Eco system, then

1. they will be far less in number than preys.
2. the preys will develop techniques to defend themselves or escape.

otherwise the Eco system will collapse.